# Making a list from a list in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of data including dates, values etc. I would like to make another list out of this list which would be based on dates.

My example: Column A = item; B = date; C = value; D = formula, that returns value from column C if date in B is less than date of today (if(b1

```
    A             B        C        D
1....abc........mar.19.....100€.......100€........................................
2....def.........jun.19......200€.......200€......................................
3....ghi.........jan.20.....150€..................................................
4....jkl..........jul.19.......300€........300€...................................
5...mno.......sep.20.....250€.....................................................
```

So in my new list, I would like to get extracted Values from column A and D, but only for the rows wich have date in B < date of today. So in this case, I need new list to be made out of rows 1, 2 and 5. And I need this to be formula based, so when i add or change those rows it would automatically change new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A combination of `INDEX & MATCH` wrapped with `SMALL`, fixes the issue:*

[image]

- An array (CSE) formula in cell `D16`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$16:$C$21,SMALL(IF((INDEX($A$16:$C$21,,$F$15)<$E$15),MATCH(ROW($A$16:$C$21),ROW($A$16:$C$21)),""),ROWS(B16:$B$16)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Enter `=Today()` in cell `E15`.
- Cell `F15` comprises column number of data range `A16:C21`, is `2`, since *Dates* to match with cell `E15` are in Column B.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @GPQ ,, keep asking ☺